# Game: How to play "completely" a scene

Tags: python, game-engine

I'd like to play a scene in the Blender game engine (I don't mind if it uses python). Basically, I'd like to say: "Play (backward or not) from frame X until frame Y," or, if it's not possible, at least "Display frame X".

With the older versions, it seems that *IPO* actuator was used for that. However, now the *IPO* actuator does not exists anymore, and it's supposed to be replaced by the *Action* actuator. However, the only way I found to make *Action* work is to specify an action ID. So only one object can move by actuator.

Of course, I could create a new action actuator for each object, but it's just crazy to maintain if there are more than 2 objects, and I can't find a way to automate it in python.

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: That is exactly the solution. The animation system plays one action at one object. When you want to play animations at several objects you need to start playing at each single object. How else should the animation system know what animation you want to play when and how? Having a "default" action is the way Blender works, but the purpose of Blender is completely different to the purpose of the BGE.

Comment: So maybe I could set up a "super action" that could include all the actions in a scene ? Because for what I'd like to do (which is basically being able to play and stop a full simple animation), it's impossible to manually add one action for each moving object... Or maybe you have a way to create in python all the actuators?

Comment: You would need an actuator that includes all the objects. That makes much less sense than to play single actions. If you really think setting up animation is too much work for you - you can let Blender do it for you (via Blender script).

Comment: Does such an animator exists? An in Blender scripts, I didn't find how to create animators, in bge I always need to manually create them...

Comment: I do not know. maybe someone wrote such a script already. I'm not up-to-date with that. It should not be that difficult to write such a script.

Comment: The problem is not the script, but the function: I can't find a function that create an actuator.

Comment: I mean you create a Blender script (not a BGE script). Blender can add and remove logic bricks (the BGE can't do that). See https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.ops.logic.html?highlight=actuator_add#bpy.ops.logic.actuator_add